# YouTube API No such file or directory

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm a PHP newb trying out the YouTube API demo at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMhN6pCAZWo.

I have the google-api-php-client and yt-samples-php-master directories that he says to download at

www.mysite.com/video/google-api-php-client and 
www.mysite.com/video/yt-samples-php-master

the search.php file is in yt-samples-php-master and I have replicated the video and set:

```
if ($_GET['q'] && $_GET['maxResults']) {
set_include_path("./google-api-php-client/src");
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google_Client.php';
require_once 'contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
```

I can get to www.mysite.com/videos/yt-samples-php-master/search.php fine but when I search I get message:

Warning: require_once(Google_Client.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myusername/mysite.com/videos/yt-samples-php-master/search.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Google_Client.php' (include_path='./google-api-php-client/src/') in /home/myusername/mysite.com/videos/yt-samples-php-master/search.php on line 17.

I noticed that the files Google make available have a typo `require_once 'contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php';`
should be `require_once 'contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';`

but that doesn't seem to help. Any clues would be very gratefully received!

EDIT: I've also set 755 recursively through videos directory to sub-directories and files

Comment: Do you want to get details from that video or get all videos?

Comment: Hi.  To begin with I just want to use the search on search.php and get the videos returned.  Once i get the include locations correct I'd definitely like to try and learn the additional options

Answer (score 3):

It's late. but someone may be looking for this in future.

Solution:

- Google's php client uses composer, so, you've to put the path to the autoload file. 

  Link: [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#basic-example)
- Remove or comment out **require_once()** methods for **Google_Client.php** &  **contrib/Google_YoutubeService.php**
- Rename class name from **Google_YoutubeService** to **Google_Service_YouTube** while instantiating

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this `./` and try this following format

```
set_include_path("google-api-php-client/src");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that and error just changes to:  `Warning: require_once(Google_Client.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/mysite.com/videos/yt-samples-php-master/search.php on line 18

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Google_Client.php' (include_path='google-api-php-client/src') in /home/username/mysite.com/videos/yt-samples-php-master/search.php on line 18`

Comment: @Stuart Brown i have same problem. if do u solved? please help me... thanks.

Comment: the answer I gave above (Jan 6 at 21:23) is what worked for me.

Comment: i solved diferent way. before i am created developer console "server key" when i re-create key "browser key". this time work for me. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Is google-api-php-client in the same folder as your project. Make sure you are setting the include to point to that directory. And that directory is 755'ed.

Also in latest (v1.0) php library they changed placing of sources to

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';

require_once 'Google/Service/Youtube.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I've come back to this after a little while.  I've managed to get the search.php example to work by:

- In search.php changing the require statements to:
  require_once './google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
  require_once './google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';
  and commenting out the set_include_path and following two require_once lines.

This lead to a fatal error saying that class Google_Service_YouTube could not be found in Google_YouTubeService.php.  In that file there was however a class called Google_YouTube_Service which I renamed and then it worked!